# How to use batch transaction feature programatically?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Using the multisend contract and the available method for making a batch transaction is there but the transactions take place with a single nonce where as on the website the batch transaction button executes all the available nonces.

Adding some screenshots for ref:
[image]

The code used to execute this is given on [link](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/protocol-kit#api-reference)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The batch-execution button for the queued transactions on the web-interface executes all fully-signed transactions with consecutive nonces.

This means each of those transactions needs to be queued and signed first.

To execute such transactions we also use the `MultiSendCallOnly` contract. But it is a `MultiSend` of `SafeTransactions` instead of a `SafeTransaction` containing a `MultiSend` call.

To implement this, encode each SafeTransaction using this function:

```
export const getMultiSendTxs = (
  txs: TransactionDetails[],
  chain: ChainInfo,
  safeAddress: string,
  safeVersion: string,
): MetaTransactionData[] => {
  const readOnlySafeContract = getReadOnlyGnosisSafeContract(chain, safeVersion)

  return txs
    .map((tx) => {
      if (!isMultisigDetailedExecutionInfo(tx.detailedExecutionInfo)) return

      const args = extractTxInfo(tx, safeAddress)
      const sigs = getSignatures(args.signatures)

      const data = readOnlySafeContract.encode('execTransaction', [
        args.txParams.to,
        args.txParams.value,
        args.txParams.data,
        args.txParams.operation,
        args.txParams.safeTxGas,
        args.txParams.baseGas,
        args.txParams.gasPrice,
        args.txParams.gasToken,
        args.txParams.refundReceiver,
        sigs,
      ])

      return {
        operation: OperationType.Call,
        to: safeAddress,
        value: '0',
        data,
      }
    })
    .filter(Boolean) as MetaTransactionData[]
}
```

The result of this call needs to be encoded using the safe-core-sdk:

```
const multiSendTxData = encodeMultiSendData(multiSendTxs)
```

And lastly using ethers call the `multiSend` function of the `MultiSendCallOnly` contract with the resulting data:

```
await multiSendContract.contract.connect(provider.getSigner()).multiSend(multiSendTxData)
```